# Having issues with Locale while using formatNumber function from angular core

Tags: javascript, angular, localization

I am trying to format a number in Angular using https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber#formatnumber

My code looks like this,

```
  import {formatNumber} from '@angular/common';
  var testNumber = 123456.23;
  var x = formatNumber(Number(testNumber), "en-IN", "1.2-2")
  console.log(x)
```

this prints the following on console,

123,456.2

All the decimal formatting is fine, but this seems to be formatted based on localte "en-US" and not "en-IN"

For "en-IN", I expected the output to be

1,23,456.2

Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 1):

The `@angular/common` method `formatNumber`, which has a dependency on `@angular/core` doesn't care about the region part of the locale, if the exact locale wasn't found. It then solely uses the [Primary Language Subtag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#section-2.2.1).

This can be seen in the source code here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/i18n/locale_data_api.ts#L53

A workaround would be to use the `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` method. This will give you the correct output.

```
testNumber.toLocaleString('en-IN') // => 1,23,456.23
```

If you do, however, want to keep using the `formatNumber` method from angular, you can register your own `localeData` with the `registerLocaleData` method, exported from `@angular/common`.

On a further note, the `localeData` for `en-IN` [seems to already exist](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/locales/en-IN.ts) in `@angular/common`, so you might just have to register it, to use it.

Here's an example on how you can use it:

```
import { formatNumber, registerLocaleData } from "@angular/common";
import enIN from "@angular/common/locales/en-IN";

registerLocaleData(enIN, 'en-IN')

console.log(formatNumber(123456.23, "en-IN", "1.2-2")); // => 1,23,456.23
```

Comment: thanks Keimeno, would it be possible for you to give me a snippet of how to use registerLocaleData. Is it possible to reigister locale based on variable

Comment: @Goli I've updated my answer to provide an example on how to use `registerLocaleData`, and make it work as expected